# numpy scalar conversion magic in math.sin()?

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion, dynamic-typing

Python makes a point of not converting when it's not clear what operation should be applied, which is why `'4.0' + 3.0` rightly fails. But I've been using numpy and I've noticed that `math.sin(np.array([1.0]))` *does* work, even though `math.sin('1.0')` does not. Did numpy somehow know a float was expected, or does math.sin() actually try converting some things?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. `math.sin()` and presumably all other functions in the `math` module automatically run class-based input objects through `float()`, which checks for the special method `Class.__float__(self)`. For instance, `math.sin()` also converts the following class:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __float__(self):
        return self.x
math.sin(Test(1.0))
```

Interesting... Another dark corner of python.

Comment: They probably just call `float()` in it. `float()` calls `x.__float__()` on types that have it.

Comment: No, if they just called `float`, that would convert `'1.0'` to `1.0`.

Comment: Maybe they only do it on class-based objects, as in the ones declared in python with a class keyword.